# Why is ifconfig with 4 values?

Tags: 16.04, networking

I have output like this

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
          inet addr:*.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet addr:*.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet addr:*.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

This is what I got

```
ifconfig | awk '/Link encap:/ {print $1}'
br-498e85899682
docker0
enp3s0
lo
```

Why do I have four IP addresses?

Comment: Looks like you might have virtual and physical ports mixed.  127.0.0.1 you will have regardless because of loopback, and 192.168.0.12 might be virtual, but I could be mistaken. Edit your question and give the output of `ifconfig | awk '/Link encap:/ {print $1}'`

Comment: @Terrance Take a look my edit,please!

Comment: lo is loopback.  enp3s0 is physical.  docker0 is used by Docker itself.  And I am not sure what the one that begins with br- is.  So, that looks like 1 actual ethernet connection.  The rest are created by applications.

Comment: I was going to add a comment but Terrance said everything correctly